# Is it good practice to out MySQL or Apache in /opt/ folder?

Tags: linux, devops

So at my company they want to put all the application software in The /opt/application folder.  This strikes me as odd because they consider  server daemon like Apache and MySQL as application sofrwarw...but they already usually have a place like /use/bin . They're logic is that it will make patching the system easier. I don't see how.. can someone clarify as to any pros and cons

Comment: If you're building and/or deploying your own versions of software like Apache or MySQL and not using any OS-supplied default, placing it in `/usr/bin` is a perfectly wonderful way to break your operating system.  And see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Answer (score 4):

The `/usr` directory is mostly treated as being fully owned by the package management systems in most Linux distributions. If you try and place your own binaries in those locations, there is a good chance something might get broken. Safe places to store your own things usually include `/usr/local`, `/opt`, and `/srv` on most distros. Putting things you locally build and manage under `/opt` is perfectly fine, and not unusual.

Comment: This are not locally built applicationsl, just stock Apache and Mysql